# Character with byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0xa6 in encoding utf8 has no equivalent in encoding latin1

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding

I am importing a CSV file into a PostgreSQL table through the PostgreSQL import functionality, but I get this error:

```
character with byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0xa6 in encoding utf8 has no equivalent in encoding latin1
```

Please help me out with this...

Comment: Hi, Which piece of code is giving you this error. Its always best to show us code on SO

Comment: It might be worth you [reading this Q&A - UTF-8 All the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: what code i should show u , as i am simply uploading a cvs file at postgresql server in godaddy...

Comment: Well to be complete. 1) The PHP code doing the upload. 2) The schema for the table or tables that you are loading. 3) The line from the CSV file that first causes this problem, plus a couple of lines either side of the problem line

Comment: i am "importing" a csv file into postgress table through the postgress import functionality... plz try to understand that... not using any php code for uploading...
Same import function is working at my localhost, but not on Godaddy postgress db server

Comment: Ah, that was NOT CLEAR from your original question. Maybe if you added that to your question, you would get some useful help

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to import an UTF-8 file that contains the character `…` (“horizontal ellipsis”, Unicode code point 2026).

This character cannot be encoded in LATIN1, so you will not be able to do that.

Either use a database with encoding UTF8 or edit the import file to remove the character.

Comment: Yep, Unicode has 137274 characters (currently). Latin1 has 256. @Amit, do both Unicode _and Latin1_ serve some purpose for you? If so, you need a plan.

Comment: Nitpick: LATIN1 has fewer than 256 characters.